# Admin backend: display sum of orders in multiple currencies

Tags: magento-1.9

in Magento 1.9 I created 3 websites and assigned to them different currencies: eur, gbp, usd

I need to display in the dashboard the global values of each parameter (orders, revenues, etc) in eur, summing the values from each website and automatically converting gbp and usd to eur.

I.e. If
Ws 1 total sales: 100 eur
Ws 2 total sales: 50 usd
Ws 3 total sales: 10 gbp

I want to display in the dashboard (Magento should convert gbp and usd to eur then calculate the global sum)
Global sales: 156 eur

How can I do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The global sum for all websites is already displayed on the Magento admin dashboard, regardless of the order's currency. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RobbieAverill Magento admin dashboard  global sum of all websites displays the sum of eur sales only. Usd and gbp sales are not included.

Answer (score 1):

Solved

Input (or have webservicex atutomatically import them) conversion rates in  System > manage currency > rates